# Amazon AWS: Adding more new server vs upgrading current servers configuration for seasonal traffic spikes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are hosting our website using Amazon AWS. We get seasonal traffic spikes i.e. almost every month we get such situation.

Which is better in such cases:

1. Getting more similar servers to serve additional traffic? OR
2. Upgrading configuration of existing servers on such peak traffic days and downgrading these later?

Answer (score 0):

Its always recommended to scale out (Getting more server instances) for your web servers. This you can automate using AWS [autoscaling](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) configurations.

However its better to carryout a load test and find the server type which provides the optimum performance per given cost, rather guessing the capacity needs. Generally you can start with [M series](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) if you are not sure of the base requirements for your application(Memory, CPU, IOPS& etc.)

Finally do a load test to simulate the spike load, to evaluate the readiness of your setup.

Comment: We already have 5 servers running, once we adding 2-3 more for seasonal peaks, we need to do changes in our CI code to automate deployment to these servers too. Isn't it better in this scenario to scale up so that we don't require to change CI/auto-deployment process?

Comment: Then in short term you can scale up. The tradeoff is the cost since you need to allocate capacity for peak load. In long term go for deployment pipeline native to aws so jenkins don't get limited to the number of instances running.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the price of having 2 `t2.small` instances or 1 `t2.medium` is pretty much the same so as a 1-off you'd be better off with just running a larger server, mainly because this would be easy for you to set up.

However this is not a good long term solution, as stated previously using an autoscaling instance would be the best solution in terms of cost since you can set a cloudWatch alarm to scale up or down based on demand (ie. memory consumption).

Based on this I would advise you to go with the option `2` you have listed.

Answer (score 0):

This is  pretty much the use case for [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/).  You can configure it to run on a small number of servers, but if the load gets too high to add additional instances.